# Smallest number from an array

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is my challenge:

> Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them in such a manner that they form the smallest number possible.
>
> The result is going to be very large, hence return the result in the form of a string.
>
> If I consider input array as {20, 1, 5} then all permutations are as below:
>
> 2015, 2051, 1205, 1520, 5201, 5120 but as 1205 is smallest hence it should be the result.
>
> Input array {20, 1, 5}
>
> Result:  1205

Here is the method signature:

```
private String getSmallestNumber(Integer[] nums) { 

}
```

What algorithm should I use?

Similar type of question asked on:

http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=380

Comment: I know this is probably homework, but the prompt isn't even clear.

Comment: I sort the array and override Comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completed my code but please suggest me better algorithm

```
private String getSmallestNumber(Integer[] nums) {

    String[] arr = new String[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = String.valueOf(nums[i]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return (a + b).compareTo(b + a);
        }
    });

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : arr) {
        sb.append(s);
    }

    while (sb.charAt(0) == '0' && sb.length() > 1) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I do not know for sure if I understand your question correctly. If you just sort the array in ascending order and print it, wouldn't that be the smallest number?

Comment: Its not sorting the array, it concatenating of 2 integer A+B and B+A find out which is lower.

Comment: See if you have an array {9,4,2,5,1}, the smallest integer you can make is 12459 right? which is the same as sorting the array in ascending order. Atleast that's what I can understand from the example you gave. If there is a simple way to achieve the objective, always use that.

Comment: Consider input as {20, 1, 5} if you sort then {1, 5, 20} if you make integer 1520 which is not correct, The correct solution is {1, 20, 5} which will make 1205.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that part.  Your way is good enough and neat. 
You can use recursive function to achieve the objective as well but it probably will take more time. 
Also you can split the arrays into different arrays of equal length, sort them in ascending and then recombine them by comparing the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to sort the array using a custom comparator that compares digit-by-digit. In other words, given two numbers, compare the most-significant-digit of the first number to most-significant-digit of the second number. Then compare the second digits, and so on, until you reach the end of one of the numbers, or the digits aren't equal. The number with the lower digit goes first in the answer.

For example 20 comes before 5 because 2 is less than 5. 1000 comes before 99 because 1 is less than 9. 123789 comes before 1239 because 7 is less than 9.

So the trick is to scale the smaller number by multiplying by 10 until both numbers have the same number of digits. For example, given a six-digit number and a four-digit number like

```
123789
  1239
```

you need to multiply the four-digit number by 100 so both numbers have the same number of digits

```
123789
123900
```

Then a simple integer comparison tells you that 123789 comes before 1239. So the code for the comparator looks like this

```
int compare( int a, int b )
{
    int special = b - a;  // special case, e.g. 123 and 123000

    if ( a <= b ) {
        for ( int n = 1; n <= b; n *= 10 )
            if ( n > a )
                a *= 10;
    } else {
        for ( int n = 1; n <= a; n *= 10 )
            if ( n > b )
                b *= 10;
    }

    if ( a == b )
        return special;
    else
        return a - b;
}
```

There is a special case where the two numbers end up being equal after scaling. For example, given the numbers 123000 and 123, the correct order is to put 123000 before 123, since that puts the three zeros in the array first, i.e. 123000123 is better than 123123000. Hence a special case is needed to choose the **larger** number first, if the numbers are equal after scaling. Hence, the need for the variable called `special`.